# Cannot add SSL certificate on ELB using Ansible

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to create a elastic load balancer and use existing SSL certificate to secure it as follows -

```
---
  - name: Setting up Elastic Load Balancer
    hosts: local
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    vars_files:
      - vars/global_vars.yml
    tasks:
      - local_action:
          name: "TestLoadbalancer" 
          module: ec2_elb_lb
          state: present
          region: 'us-east-1'
          zones:
            - us-east-1c
          listeners:
            - protocol: http
              load_balancer_port: 80
              instance_port: 80
          listeners:
            - protocol: ssl
              load_balancer_port: 443 
              instance_protocol: tcp
              instance_port: 7286
              ssl_certificate_id: "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:server-certificate/LB_cert"

      - local_action:
          name: "TestLoadbalancer" 
          module: ec2_elb_lb
          state: present
          region: 'us-east-1'
          zones:
            - us-east-1c
          listeners:
            - protocol: http
              load_balancer_port: 80
              instance_port: 80
          health_check:
              ping_protocol: http
              ping_port: 80
              ping_path: "/"
              response_timeout: 5
              interval: 30
              unhealthy_threshold: 2
              healthy_threshold: 10
```

But it is not adding the listener: SSL - TCP

Another listener is added and is visible in the console: HTTP/80

Why the SSL one is missing? Am I missing any required parameters?

Comment: Any error messages when you run it with `-vvvv`?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding multiple keys with the name "listeners":

```
listeners:
  - protocol: http
    ...
listeners:
  - protocol: ssl
    ...
```

But glancing at the example in the documentation it should be:

```
listeners:
  - protocol: http
    ...
  - protocol: ssl
    ...
```

Comment: Tried that way too, same result.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps the second task is interfering with the first? I see that "name" is a required parameter for the module as "The name of the ELB". So you're creating 2 ELB with the same name, one with 2 listeners and one with just port 80 and a health_check.  (I don't use the ec2_elb_lb module, so I'm not sure what the behaviour should be)